# count number of rows in flask templates

Tags: python, templates, loops, count, flask

i have send a variable from my views to templates which consist of the data from database

this is what i am using in my template

```
{% for i in data %}             
    <tr>
        <td>{{i.id}}</td>
        <td>{{i.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{i.email}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

there are seven entries in this loop , i need to show count lease suggest how can i do this

Answer (score 48):

Inside the loop you can access a special variable called `loop` and you can see the number of items with `{{ loop.length }}`

This is all you can do with loop auxiliary variable:

- **loop.index**    The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
- **loop.index0**   The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)
- **loop.revindex** The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1 indexed)
- **loop.revindex0**    The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0 indexed)
- **loop.first**    True if first iteration.
- **loop.last** True if last iteration.
- **loop.length**   The number of items in the sequence.
- **loop.cycle**    A helper function to cycle between a list of sequences. See the explanation below.
- **loop.depth**    Indicates how deep in deep in a recursive loop the rendering currently is. Starts at level 1
- **loop.depth0**   Indicates how deep in deep in a recursive loop the rendering currently is. Starts at level 0

**EDIT:**

To see the count of items outside de for loop you can generate another variable from your view like `count_data = len(data)` or you can use the `length` filter:

```
Data count is {{ data|length }}:
{% for i in data %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{i.id}}</td>
      <td>{{i.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{i.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{i.email}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but now it returns the loop length seven times like 7777777

Answer (score 2):

> {{ data|length }}

this works perfect we not need to use this in loop  just use any where in the template
**even we dont need to send another variable from views**