# Download File From Another Directory In Flask

Tags: python, linux, flask, sendfile

Im New In Flask . I'm try to make download list of /var/ directory files but 
i can't find any way to make this link .
any file could be in this directory so tempfile could solve this problem .
i don't know the file so i can't copy file in flask directory ,
could any one tell me how can i make download link for file like this ?

Comment: Have a look at [send_file()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file) and [send_from_directory()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory)

Comment: thanks alot . i try send_file but i can't make it work but after your suggestion i use send_from_directory and this worked as i want. thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used flask, but have some experience with Django.
From quickly looking at the flask docs ([rendering_templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)) you would have to pass a context variable to the rendering function, then add it to the jinja template.

I would also suggest designating a different folder to place downloads, as giving users access to your /var/ folder can pose a security concern.

See below:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

dloads_dir = '/var/www/mysite/downloads/'
dloads = os.listdir(dloads_dir).sort()
dloads_src = ['/downloads/{}'.format(i) for i in dloads]

@app.route('/Downloads')
def list_downloads():

    return render_template('downloads.html', dloads=dloads, dloads_src=dloads_src)
```

Then in the html (should I say Jinja2) template:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% for file in dloads %}
    <a href="{{ dloads_src[loop.index0] }}" download>{{ file }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

[Here's where I found the loop.index method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739359/7105494)

(1) Edit: Fixed my bad html